# GSheets- Automate reminder e-mail to client 1-2 days prior to appointment

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation, workflow, google-forms

I'm looking for a way (google app script, add-on, or otherwise) that will automate an appointment reminder e-mail using cell values in my google spreadsheet. Currently, my work flow is like this:

1. I fill out my client ID and appointment date google form.
2. Mail merge sends a confirmation e-mail to client that informs them of their appointment date and time.

**I'd like for the 3rd step to be that an e-mail is automatically sent 1-2 days prior to the appointment date and maybe a 4th step to send the e-mail on the appointment date to remind them.**

**[Here is my sheet with dummy data and without mail merge formatting:](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y6hbnSdxlw-dk7k4L0TFitbzF0NA-iRjcrWcJZEjhVU/edit?usp=sharing)**

Although I've looked on these forums and stack exchange, I cannot find a solution to my problem. I've found that people are trying to achieve similar, but mostly want e-mails routed to a static e-mail/e-mails. My needs are more dynamic. Please help.

**Here's what what I'm working with:**

```
function sendEmail() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-1;   // Number of rows to process
// Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, sheet.getLastColumn());
// Fetch values for each row in the Range.
var data = dataRange.getValues();
//Logger.log(data)

for (i in data) {
  var row = data[i];
  var date = new Date();
  date.setHours(0);
  date.setMinutes(0);
  date.setSeconds(0);
  //Logger.log(date);
  var sheetDate = new Date(row[9]);
 //Logger.log(sheetDate);
  var Sdate = Utilities.formatDate(date,'GMT-0600','MM:dd:yyyy')
  var SsheetDate = Utilities.formatDate(sheetDate,'GMT-0600', 'MM:dd:yyyy')
     Logger.log(Sdate+' =? '+SsheetDate)
        if (Sdate == SsheetDate){
          var emailAddress = row[8]; // Patient Email
          var message = row[6];row[7];       // Date and Time
          var subject = "Your appointment is in 1 day!." +message;
          MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
          //Logger.log('SENT :'+emailAddress+'  '+subject+'  '+message)
            }    
   }
  }
```

What I've referred to and tried to make work for me:

[Referencing by date/day- Google Forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/docs/5c-OmxOW-Vo):

[Emails sent based on date- Google Forums:](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F11025491%2Fgoogle-apps-script-send-email-based-on-date-in-cell&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNHbON8NJ06rjAla7MFeoK-JdAYGWg)

[Emails sent based on date - Stack Overflow:](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F11025491%2Fgoogle-apps-script-send-email-based-on-date-in-cell&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNHbON8NJ06rjAla7MFeoK-JdAYGWg)

**[Due Date Reminders - Stack Overflow](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F40611633%2Fsetting-due-date-reminders-in-sheets&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNGiXF3N7Mf9sooqE1NOsuIsSdK7FA)**

Answer (score 0):

## Create a calendar event with a default set of notifications

Here's a function that creates an event on your calendar with default notifications of 1 day, 2 days and 1 hour.  You supply with an array that contains
Client Name, Appointment Date and Appointment Time as follows:
['Client Name','11/31/2017','1:30:00 PM']

```
function testCreateEventWithReminders()
{
  createEventWithReminders(['Harry Dog','11/20/2017','1:30:00 PM']) 
}
//eA=[clientName,date,time]
function createEventWithReminders(eA)
{
  var minute=60*1000;
  var hour=60*minute;
  var day=24*hour;
  var cal=CalendarApp.getCalendarById('CalendarID');//You need to supply your calendarID
  var now=new Date().valueOf()
  var start=new Date(eA[1] + ' ' + eA[2]);
  var endValue=start.valueOf() + (hour);  
  var end=new Date(endValue);
  var event=cal.createEvent(eA[0], start, end);
  event.addEmailReminder(24*60);//reminders in minutes
  event.addEmailReminder(2*24*60);
  event.addEmailReminder(60);
}
```

Above you will need to insert your calendar ID.  If you run displayCalendarInfo you should be able to determine what the calendar names and id's are.

```
function displayCalendarInfo()//Use this function to determine calendar names and ids.
{
  var cals=CalendarApp.getAllCalendars();
  var s='Calendar Information';
  for(var i=0;i<cals.length;i++)
  {
    s+=Utilities.formatString('<br />Name: %s Id: %s', cals[i].getName(),cals[i].getId());
  }
  s+='<br /><input type="button" value="Close" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />';
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(s).setWidth(1200).setHeight(450);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Calendar Data');
}
```

If you want to create your own non default reminders you can add more elements to the input array

**Additional Instructions:**

1. The input to the function createEventWithReminders(eA) is an array in the form ['client name','mm/dd/yyyy','hh:mm:ss AM'] where the date and time are for the appointment.
2. I'm assuming that you can integrate this function into your spreadsheet some how. Personally, I would probably would have made it into a contained webapp because I like to use Siri to do a lot of my data entry thus eliminating the need to type on my mobile device and providing me the opportunity to enter reminders as I proceed through the day without my laptop.

Comment: Hey there, Cooper, thanks for helping me. Your solution might be a game changer for me, in a good way. I don't mind creating a calendar event in my GCal, but is there a way to auto-send thereminder to my client? I don't need to be reminded would rather the script pull my clients' emails from a column and auto-send.

I tried the script as-is adding my Cal ID. The script gives me the option of running 2 functions: testCreate and Create. testCreate runs but does nothing, and Create brings up an error: TypeError: Cannot read property "1" from undefined. (line 13, file "CreateReminder").What now?

Comment: Ah, Cooper, I just saw that multiple events were created. However, they were created on November 20th, the date that you defined. I tried modifying by replacing with 'row[2]','row[6]','row[7]' which are my client name, date, and time columns. But nothing was created. Is there a way to make the App draw from this info from the sheet? Sorry I'm so new and lost. I should maybe add: a google form will be filled out that will fill the columns I want the app to draw data from.

Comment: See additional comments